# C++ CListControl - check if selected

Tags: c++, getselection, controlbox

I've got a ListControl box and I want to enable a textbox if the user clicks on a button there.
I've allready tried to update the dialog via an "OnLeftButtonUp" function which works quite well if I click outside the ListControl but when I click INSIDE the box nothing happens...
Any ideas why?
Cheers

Comment: Unclear. This is probably specific to  Windows, please edit question and add tag. And I have no clue what `getselection` and `controlbox` are ...

Comment: And without any code, it's gonna be hard to answer that question, please add an MVCE : http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve